# project.json solution project reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm playing with ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and I wanted add reference to `project.json` file to my Database Project. Here it is:

`project.json`

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot"
    ],
    "packExclude": [
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta1",
        "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta1",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "DataManagement": ""    <----- THIS IS MY PROJECT WITHIN SOLUTION
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": { },
        "aspnetcore50": { }
    }
}
```

DataManagement project is simply **Class Library**, however I tried with **ASP.NET 5 Class Library**. Both project types fail and this is what I see in visual studio:

[image: Solution View]

Project is building properly and producing (of course) Datamanagement.dll, but this library isn't found by Web project.

To be exact, below there are target versions of both projects:

```
DataManagement: KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-rc1-10846
Web:            KRE-CLR-x86.1.0.0-rc1-10846
```

Comment: make sure your library is targeting the same .net framework version

Comment: I updated question. Target versions are the same.

Comment: did you try specifying the assembly version? probably `1.0.0.0`: `"DataManagement": "1.0.0.0"`

Comment: or, i think you can still right click > add references, did you try that?

Comment: @DLeh - I tried both ways :/

Comment: Where does your DataManagement project exist in correlation with the project that you're referrencing it from?

Comment: In the same solution it is under Data/DataManagement. It is compiling properly, because there is only 1 empty class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, both projects need to have the same parent folder.

For example, this pattern works:

- /mysolution/project1/project.json
- /mysolution/project2/project.json

But this won't:

- /mysolution/sub1/project1/project.json
- /mysolution/sub2/project2/project.json

Often the easiest is to ensure both projects have the same common parent folder.

But, if they can't, you can add a `global.json` file to the "solution" folder and indicate where the sources are to be located:

```
{
    "sources": ["sub1", "sub2"]
}
```

Comment: I'll try that and let you know. Thanks for effort.

Comment: working, thanks :) I didn't realize that global.json even exist, because I created Empty vNext project - it means without src folder  and `global.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a version. Try:

```
"DataManagement": "1.0.0-*"
```

Comment: I tried with explicit version number and with * at the end. I think the problem is in my local environment because today, when I opend solution, everything was red - all references, namespaces, methods - literally everything. Restart of Visual Studio didn't help.

Comment: You can also just use `"*"`, so you don't have to remember to update it in future.